# Blazor is disconnection when switching to another path

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a strange issue in my blazor app. I don't know why but when I navigate from a specific path of my app to another path then I get a 400 disconnect message in my browser console.

When I navigate back to the entry point the connection becomes established again.

There are these paths right now

1. /
2. /Admin/Users
3. /Admin/Users/{name}

Admin/Users shows me a list of all employees from my SQL-Database.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>E-Mail</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Aktion</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var mitarbeiter in UserManager.Users)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@mitarbeiter.FirstName @mitarbeiter.LastName</td>
                <td>@mitarbeiter.Email</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="/Admin/Users/@mitarbeiter.UserName" class="btn btn-primary">
                        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, each employee has a a-Tag to /Admin/Users/{name}. When I click on it, everything works as expected. When I use the navigation now to go back to /Admin/Users then the connection will be terminated. It becomes established again when I go to / or to /Admin/Users manually again.

The navigation is defined as:

```
<AuthorizeView Roles="Administratoren">
    <Authorized>
        <div class="sb-sidenav-menu-heading">System</div>
        <nav class="sb-sidenav-menu-nested nav">
            <NavLink href="/Admin/Users" class="nav-link">Benutzer</NavLink>
        </nav>
    </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

The page /Admin/Users/{name} just displays some razor components to edit the employee. All sites uses the same default layout which contains the blazor.server.js

```
<script src="/_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

Does anybody know, how I can fix this issue or what is causing it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, I added the following code to my _Host.cshtml

```
<base href="~/" />
```